# Is there any other way to adopt a child in skyrim WITHOUT any mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

when I killed grelod the kind in skyrim I still couldn't adopt a child even if I tried to watch something on youtube and I cant get any mods instaled even if  I 
tried it just wouldn't work

Comment: and I'm on a.pc

Answer (score 7):

You need to meet a couple of prerequisites before you can adopt

1. Buy the hearthfire DLC and make sure that it is installed
2. Own a house or homestead and purchase a children's bedroom

---

The only way to be able to adopt a child from Honorhall Orphanage is to complete the quest "Innocence Lost", aka kill Grelod for the dark brotherhood

Also you might have to wait a few days for Constance to calm down after Grelod is killed

---

But there are other children who roam the land of Skyrim that you are able to adopt, no need to go to the orphanage

**Alesan** - In Dawnstar near the mines

**Blaise** - Just outside Solitude at Katla's Farm

**Lucia** - In Whiterun near the Gildergreen

**Sofie** - In Windhelm, Gray Quarter

---

Also, you have the ability to adopt any child in Skyrim at Honorhall Orphanage if their parents die

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoption

Answer (score 0):

Once Grelod is killed for the DB questline trigger, a woman there takes over the orphanage.  To adopt, you have to own a home that has a room for a child, such as Breezehome with the requisite upgrade.

I think she's essential, but if you go on some rampage in the orphanage and there are no adult survivors, you will not be able to adopt without mods.